# Storing value of calculation that query result is being ordered by with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I'm new to rails but I still feel I should know the answer to this. Drawing a complete blank.

I have the following query that returns the expected results. However I want to also store the value the calculation they are being ordered by returns.

What is the best way of extracting this value.

Here is the line of code

```
@service = Service.order("ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lat lon)', 4326))").limit(10)
```

As I said it returns the correct results but I'd also like to find the distance for each result

Thank you

Comment: I think you should explain better what result you wish for, some examples may help understand

Comment: Apologies, I get 10 Services in order from this query, they are ordered by the ST_Distance calculation, what is the best way of getting the result of this calculation for each service that is returned. So I have the services in order and the distance value that has ordered them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@services = Service.select("*, ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lat lon)', 4326)) as st_distance").order("st_distance").limit(10)
```

the objects you get back in `@services` (note i changed this to the plural in keeping with convention) should have an additional method `.st_distance`, which is what i set the results of that function to be called with `as st_distance`

Comment: Works perfectly and makes perfect sense, thank you vey much, I appreciate it